# 3 Columns Minipage with Alignments

Tags: horizontal-alignment, minipage

I have the following title with bad alignments.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[landscape,margin=10mm]{geometry}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}[r]{0.19\textwidth}
  \rule{30mm}{30mm}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.58\textwidth}
  \begin{center}
    {\Huge Title}
  \end{center}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[r]{0.19\textwidth}
  \rule{30mm}{30mm}
\end{minipage}%

\end{document}
```

[image]
How can we make same the distances marked by red color?

Comment: What do you need the minipages for?

Comment: I am preparing a certificate of participation. Two different logos of the same size appear on the sides and a title in the middle.

Comment: Why not use a table? I recommend you calculate the width of the logo using the `calc` package using `\widthof{<argument>}` and then use a newlength for it.

Comment: @azetina I won't recommend that. The placement can be done easier, I think.

Comment: Logos are 3cm by 3cm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the reason why your example was not giving the desire result was because `0.19\textwidth` was much larger than 30mm which `\rule{30mm}{30mm}` is.

[image]

Here is mwe:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[showframe,landscape,margin=10mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{calc}

\pagestyle{empty}
\newcommand{\logo}{\rule{30mm}{30mm}} % More than likely an \includegraphics here

\newlength\logowidth
\setlength{\logowidth}{\widthof{\logo}} % Place the logo declaration here

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{minipage}[c]{\logowidth}
  \logo
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.58\textwidth}
  \begin{center}
    {\Huge Title}
  \end{center}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[c]{\logowidth}
  \logo
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is a version with graphics:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[showframe,landscape,margin=10mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{mwe} % For graphics purpose only.

\pagestyle{empty}
\newcommand{\logo}{\includegraphics[width=30mm]{example-image-a}}

\newlength\logowidth
\setlength{\logowidth}{\widthof{\logo}}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{minipage}[c]{\logowidth}
  \logo
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.58\textwidth}
  \begin{center}
    {\Huge Title}
  \end{center}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[c]{\logowidth}
  \logo
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I can propose a simple solution with `tabularx`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[landscape,margin=10mm, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

{\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{>{\centering\huge\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{\hspace{\parindent}}m{30mm}Xm{30mm}@{\hspace{\parindent}}}
  \rule{30mm}{30mm} & Title & \rule{30mm}{30mm}
\end{tabularx}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

And a third possibility using no packages (except `graphicx` and `geometry`):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[landscape,margin=10mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\hbox to \textwidth{%
\includegraphics[width=30mm, height=30mm]{example-image-a}%
\hfill%
\parbox[b][30mm][c]{0.58\textwidth}{\centering\Huge Title}% change the width of the parbox to your liking
\hfill%
\includegraphics[width=30mm, height=30mm]{example-image-b}%
}
\end{document}
```

[image]